# Matlab detect layer edge with form of parabola

Tags: matlab, dijkstra, edge-detection, hough-transform

I have this image:

[image]

and would like to get the points on the two black layers to calculate the area siz between the 2 layers.

What is the best way to proceed here? I was thinking to apply dijsktra algorithm or hough transform but it did not really work out.

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar pictures to detect parabola.However, I only need to calculate the number. When it comes to your problem, I think you can use functions such as 'bwconncomp',and calculate the area according to the two edges.

Comment: An explanation of how to use `bwconncomp` would make this a much better answer.